# Base64 Image never Renders in React

Tags: reactjs, filereader

```
import {useEffect, useState,useRef} from 'react'
function ImagePicker(props){

    const [imgg,setImage] = useState(" ")
    const [isSet,setBool] = useState(false)
    const firstRender = useRef(true); //free of reRenders


    function handleAdd(event){
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => { //callback function
         setImage(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }


    useEffect(()=>{
        if(firstRender.current){
            firstRender.current = false  
        }
        else{
            console.log("HELLO")
            setBool(true)
        }
    },[imgg])

    const box = {
        height:"40%",
        width:"100%",
        display:"flex",
        alignItems:"center",
        borderRadius:"5px",
        backgroundImage:`url('${imgg}')`
    }
    return <div className={props.customStyle}>

        {isSet ? <div style={box} onClick={handleAdd}>
            <p style={{width:"100%",textAlign:"center"}}>Click to Add Image</p>
        </div> : <input type="file" name="" id="" style={box} onChange={handleAdd}/>}
        {console.log(box.backgroundImage)}
        <img src={imgg} style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}></img>
    </div>
}

export default ImagePicker
```

FileReader function gives me a base64 encoded image which i assign to the imgg variable and upon reRendering I am able to see that the backgroundImage property is set with the url() but the image nevers shows up on the browser . Would appreciate any help . Thanks!

Comment: I think the src of the <img>-tag has to start (depending on the image format) with "data:image/jpeg;base64," for example. This is followed by the base64 string. But I'm not sure if this is the cause because I don't know the code of the FileReader function.

Comment: What I found out was png,jpeg works but heic format does not work

Comment: Then maybe the easiest solution is to convert the image to jpeg or png first.